# In Google Apps Scripts, how do I return the text value of a cell that is formatted as a date?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a bit of code using Google Apps Scripts. The code links cells from a spreadsheet to a google doc. The cells in the spreadsheet are populated based on responses from a google form. One of the questions is formatted as a date question. The response is recorded in "mm/dd/yyyy" format. One line of my code converts the response to "MMMM d, YYYY" format. (See below). The response is then linked to the google doc.

```
var Memo_Date = e.values[3]; 

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var DateColumn1 = sheet.getRange("D2:D");
DateColumn1.setNumberFormat("MMMM d, yyyy");
```

The problem is that the response is returned in a date format i.e. "3/15/18". I need "March 15, 2018". Any ideas as how to get there?

Comment: In what order are you calling these commands? If you call `setNumberFormat()` after adding a date, then it should work fine. If it makes sense for you, then you could also format the date as a string using [`formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format).

Comment: I don't see how you variable `Memo_Date` is related to the rest of the code you provided. And to where do you want to return the value of the cell? You mean, you want to access this value in Apps Script? Or you want to assign it to an Spreadsheet cell? Or insert as cell into a Google Doc? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

The following Google Script would provide a function to a spreadsheet, to convert a date into the format you requested:

```
function textFormatDate(dateString) {
  const dateObj = new Date(dateString);
  const dtf = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: '2-digit' });
  const [{ value: mo },,{ value: da },,{ value: ye }] = dtf.formatToParts(dateObj);
  return`${mo} ${da}, ${ye}`;
}
```

In a spreadsheet, you would type `=textFormatDate("3/15/18")` or use a cell reference like `=textFormatDate(C1)`.

**However** that is not precisely what you've asked for. If I've understood your question correctly, you should be able to **adapt** that code into your script as to:

1. take your GSheet response value
2. use `textFormatDate(val)` on that value
3. set the resulting formatted value into your GDoc

That is for a single value. If you need help applying to multiple values, it would be good for you to include more code context in your question, where you are handling your GSheet response value and linking that value to your GDoc. Hope this helps :)